# How to design and export a 360° photo for Facebook

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, panorama

I would like to design a 360° / panorama photo for Facebook like this one: [VRT NU 360° photo](https://www.facebook.com/vrtnu/photos/a.1842664462675776.1073741828.1778438982431658/1851372631804959/?type=3&theater)

Can someone help me with this? Can this just be made in Photoshop or do I need other programs for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of info can be found in the [Facebook 360 website](https://facebook360.fb.com/editing-360-photos-injecting-metadata/) and just by Googling you'll find there's a bunch of different ways of doing it, but I suppose the simplest is to add the missing equirectangular photosphere metadata to your image.

Download the XMP template with required projection meta tag and unzip it. ([This guy](http://tophermcculloch.com/2016/06/make-photo-work-360-photosphere-facebook/) published one such template [here](http://tophermcculloch.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/facebook-photosphere-template.jpg), just download the image).

Add your images on top, keep the document the same size, and save as JPG, making sure to retain the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

***Edit*** - I now see that you want to CREATE a graphic, rather than take a photo.  I'll still leave my answer here for anyone else that needs it though

---

I've tried several of the apps for doing this and my favorite is the Google Street View app ([iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-street-view/id904418768) / [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.street&hl=en)). It's Free.

The process involves centering a yellow dot within a circle and taking a series of photographs, while trying to maintain a constant phone position.

1. Open the app and click on the yellow camera icon and then again on "Camera" to create a new photo sphere:

   [image]
2. Take a series of photos while lining up the yellow dot inside the white circle.

   [image]

   This part is the tricky part and the more effort you put in now will lead to better stitching later. **Practice this part a lot**.

   The best tips I have:

   - Keep the phone at about eye level and in a constant position
   - Use your wrists to tilt the phone vertically
   - **Rotate your body around the phone, not the phone around your body**
   - Practice, practice, practice...really
3. Once you've taken your photos, the app will automatically begin stitching them together. I think a full sphere is 12 photos, but you can click the white check mark any time to stop capturing and start stitching.

   Below, you can see a couple of my recent ones:

   [image]
4. Tap on the photo sphere you wish to export and it will open fullscreen.  Tap on the screen again, to bring up some controls.

   [image]
5. Click on the yellow sharing icon and then select Share Privately.  You can save your photo sphere from here.

When you upload one of these images to Facebook, it will automatically realize it is a photo sphere and handle the fancy stuff on its end.